# Alternative to Scrollviewer in Telerik Silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight, telerik, scrollviewer

Our company is currently using both the Telerik Silverlight tools and the Silverlight Toolkit to accomplish what we need in our program.  Since Silverlight is dying out and the Silverlight Toolkit has not been updated since 2011, we are removing all dependencies on the Silverlight Toolkit and trying to replace those controls with a Telerik Alternative so that we are not using both toolkits.  This way our customers only needs to download a 5mb file rather than a 10mb file
I've gone through and removed just about every dependency except two, one of which is the ScrollViewer.  We use the Scrollviewer several times to create a scrollable area within another grid etc.  I've looked around and found that Telerik doesn't have a direct alternative to the ScrollViewer but they do have some scrolling functionality within their RadGridView.  That won't exactly work for us, and either way it will be slow because is we put a RadGridView where the ScrollViewer is, we would be placing it in controls that have auto sizing or measure with infinity.  According to Telerik's site: **Try not to place RadGridView in controls/panels which will measure it with infinity.** Either way that seems like it would be very cluttered in our case.
**I was wondering if there was some ScrollViewer alternative in Telerik that I'd be able to use.**  If worst comes to worst, does making our own custom ScrollViewer seem reasonable?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: More specifically, the ScrollIntoView() function in the ScrollViewerExtensions from the Silverlight 5 Toolkit needs replacing.  If there is no other control that has the built in functionality to scroll to an object within the control, then I can probably just create the method myself.

Comment: Do you mean to say there's something with the ScrollViewer control that is built-in to Silverlight?

Comment: From what I recall, if you go look at the telerik templates they all use ScrollViewer too. Though generally I hear more often of ditching the telerik controls for the sdk's as vice versa. I know from experience the telerik controls can often be big cumbersome over-complicated gobs of fun though I always found myself using a control here and there from either.

Comment: @McGarnagle ScrollViewer is a control in the Silverlight 5 Toolkit [link](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) which we are trying to not use in our program at all.  So I was wondering if there is a "Telerik" ScrollViewer control.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yeah I seen Telerik examples using ScrollViewer too :/ Since the Telerik controls are more frequently updated, we decided to go completely with only Telerik (in order to reduce the size of the application).  Eventually we are going to switch to ASP.net but for now I'm stuck doing this.

Comment: Maybe I am being dense, but what in the world do you mean? Silverlight has a built-in `ScrollViewer` control, so why would the SL Toolkit need one (and I can't see that it does have one?)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @McGarnagle Sorry, it's my fault for forgetting to mention that we as using the ScrollViewerExtensions from the Toolkit to use the built in ScrollIntoView() function on the ScrollViewer to scroll to an element in the ScrollView.  Thanks for pointing that out though, I didn't realize that the ScrollView was part of Silverlight, while the ScrollIntoView was the actual thing we're trying to replace.  That narrows the problem down a bit.

Comment: I see ... but then why not just copy-paste that one class into your own code?  It seems to be a stand-alone component.  http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/Silverlight4/Source/Controls.Toolkit/Common/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs

Comment: @McGarnagle That's what I'm probably going to end up doing.  I was just wondering if there was already something like it in the Telerik toolkit so I wouldn't just be putting extra code into the application if you know what I mean.  I'll go try it right now and if it works out I'll let you know so you can post the answer below.

Comment: @McGarnagle after pulling that cs file and one other that it relies on, everything seems to be working. Thanks for the help! Please add your answer below so I can mark it as the right answer incase anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Telerik has similar ScrollViewer extensions, but one solution would be to copy-paste the relevant code from the Silverlight Toolkit source -- the [`ScrollViewerExtensions`](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/Silverlight4/Source/Controls.Toolkit/Common/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs) class.